# How to auto deploy a mule maven project in mule management console when we run the application

Tags: maven, mule

I have created a mule maven project.It was getting builded succesfully.It is getting deployed in Mule management console(MMC) when i deployed it manually. But my requirement is to auto deploy the mule maven zip file in MMC when we run the  application as mule application with maven.So how to  deploy a mule maven zip file automatically in mule management console when we run the applicatin as mule application with maven.Please help me..

Comment: Check out the Maven Mule REST Plug-in: https://github.com/NicholasAStuart/Maven-Mule-REST-Plugin

Comment: Or this one: http://java.dzone.com/articles/automated-deployment-mule